# How to switch to a non-visible profile/person in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles

I created a 9th profile/person in chrome and want to switch to it.

The problem is that I can't see it in the `Switch person` window.

**How can I switch to the invisible 9th person/profile?**

See screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also right click the button for the current person and you 
will have a dropdown menu with all profiles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the the 9th person exists but isn't visible.

Also, there isn't any scrollbar to scroll down and see the invisible profiles/persons.

What I did is **resize the window to be bigger** in order to see the 9th profile/person.

See screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Weird. Lack of a scrollbar is a clear UI failure.